# Erro: "PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module"

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, xampp, windows-7

Estou tentando acessar o SQL Server através do XAMPP no Windows 7 64 bits, mas não estou conseguindo, já segui passo a passo os tutoriais, mas na hora de iniciar o Apache dá o erro na linha abaixo:

Linha que dá o erro

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Mensagem de erro.

> [31-Oct-2014 11:12:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable
>   to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20100525 PHP
>   compiled with module API=20121212 These options need to match  in
>   Unknown on line 0

Comment: @bigown acredito que o antigo título era mais descritivo. Por padrão o php não incluí as dlls para conexão com o SQL Server.

Comment: @gmsantos não está fácil achar um bom título para esta "pergunta". Mas o título anterior não descreve nenhuma pergunta, dúvida ou problema. Essencialmente diz quais são as tecnologias usadas, o que é função das *tags*. De fato ficou faltando uma informação agora eu vou arrumar isto.

Comment: @alessandro, qual passo a passo você seguiu ?

Comment: Título que sugiro: `php startup sqlsrv unable to initialize module`

Comment: No `phpinfo()` o item `Thread Safety` está como?

Comment: O `API=20121212` corresponde a PHP 5.5. O erro que tens é porque tentaste instalar a extensão `sqlsrv` para uma versão de PHP que não é a que tens instalada...

Comment: Qual versão do Xampp e do php ?

Comment: @gmsantos a versão do PHP é o PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze19
A versão do Xampp é 1.8.3-5-VC11

Comment: Thread Safety  enabled

Comment: possível duplicata de [Drivers pdo para sql server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48078/drivers-pdo-para-sql-server)

Answer (score 4):

O Xammp não acompanha as DLLs necessárias para a conexão com o SQL Server, é preciso baixar e copiar manualmente para a sua pasta de extensões do PHP.

Você pode baixar as [últimas versões do *driver* aqui](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Esse arquivo é um *self-extractor* que vai extrair as DLLs para o diretório que você escolher.

Feito isso, é preciso escolher a DLL adequada e copiar para a pasta `ext` do PHP. Essa [página do MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx) indica qual DLL você deve utilizar de acordo com a versão do PHP.

O XAMPP vem com a versão *Thread Safety* (TS) do PHP. Copie para a o diretório `xampp\php\ext` a dll `php_sqlsrv_XX_ts.dll`, onde `XX` corresponde a sua versão do PHP. 
Por fim, no arquivo de configuração inclua a linha referente a DLL.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_XX_ts.dll
```

Ou caso você queira usar o SQL Server com o PDO:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_XX_ts.dll
```

<strike>**Obs.:** A última versão oficial dos *drivers* do SQL Server são compatíveis até o PHP 5.4.</strike>

Se você está utilizando o PHP 5.5 ou superior, pode recorrer para um [*built* não oficial](http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html) enquanto a Microsoft não lança a nova versão oficial e [votar para priorizem o lançamento](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/790641) da versão oficial compatível.

**Update:** O *driver* oficial foi atualizado e suporta até a última versão estável do PHP (5.6)

Comment: O problema é o que vc falou mesmo, a compatibilidade do PHP .

Comment: Eu sequi estes passos agora estou fazendo http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

Comment: @Alessandro só um ponto, mesmo o sistema sendo x64, use a dll de 32 bits. A dll deve ser compatível com o php, que no caso é 32 btis

Answer (score 0):

Resumindo tudo que escrevemos.

A solução é usar a não oficial 
http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

Mas por via das dúvidas estou usando o anterior.

Comment: Resolveu regredir para o php 5.4 ? Aqui no serviço temos um server 5.5 em produção com essa dll não oficial, até hoje não tivemos nenhum problema.

Comment: Mas eu não consegui conectar nem regredindo. heheheh