# Drivers PDO para SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tentando rodar uma aplicação PHP(versão 5.5.8) com a conexão ao banco de dados SQL Server com PDO, mas retorna o seguinte erro:

> could not find driver

Já tentei habilitar funcionalidades no php.ini mas sem sucesso!

Lembrando que o banco de dados não é o problema, pois consigo acessá-lo através do SQL Management Studio normalmente.

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando?

Comment: a versão é a 5.5.8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Independente de fazer uma instalação 'limpa' ou apenas atualização algum componente(SO, PHP, VCxx e MSSQL) é altamente recomendado verificar a [compatibilidade do driver do SQL server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) com os demais componentes para não instalar nada errado. O procedimento descrito a baixo também serve para a instalação da extensão [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php).

Existe uma [tabela](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017#driver-versions) que mostra qual é a versão do driver do SQL Server compatível com a respectiva versão do PHP.

1 - Baixe o driver do site da microsoft [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

2 - Descompacte o arquivo veja versão corresponde do driver com a versão do php e se ele é thread safe ou não(ver `Thread Safety` no `phpinfo()`).

3 - Copie a dll para a pasta ext da instalação do php.

4 - Por último adicione o carregamento da extensão no php.ini e reinicie o servidor.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_VERSAO_THREAD_SAFE_OU_NAO.dll
```

Para non thread safe

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

Para thread safe

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Para verificar se extensão foi carregada corretamente crie um novo arquivo com o código:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

Caso não tenha nenhum problema o phpinfo será carregado como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra forma de verificar se driver do PDO foi instalado corretamente é usar [`getAvailableDrivers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)

```
<?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```

O resultado é algo como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlsrv
    [2] => pgsql
    [3] => sqlite
)
```

Comment: Finalmente saiu o release oficial do 5.5!

Comment: Ainda não temos um release oficial do SQL Drivers que suporta o PHP 5.6, mas podemos mostrar que é algo importante [votando aqui](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1063175)

Comment: @gmsantos, saiu driver do php5.6, é o SQLSRV32.EXE.

Comment: Pois é, já estou usando ele a algum tempo. Espero que não demorem tanto pra liberar o release compatível com PHP 7 =)

Answer (score 3):

Será necessário alguns arquivos .dll que você poderá encontrar no seguinte link:
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
Como seu PHP é o 5.5, Baixe o Arquivo SQLSRV31.

Após baixar o arquivo, você irá extrai-lo, lá você terá as dlls necessárias.

utilize o phpinfo(), para verificar qual o PHP Extension Build. [image: PHP Extension Build]
<sub>(fonte: [sysadminslife.com](http://www.sysadminslife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/php5_5-phpinfo-3.jpg))</sub>  .
no caso do exemplo você terá que copiar as dlls que tenham _nts.dll do php 5.5, ou seja:
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll e php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll,
Copie estes arquivos para os respectivos diretórios,
C:/.../php/ext e também para o C:/windows/system32/ e/ou para o C:/windows/SysWOW64 caso sejá computador de 64bits.

Feito isso você deverá abrir o php.ini e na sessão de extension você deverá acrescentar as seguintes linhas:

extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll

e remover o ";" da linha extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll caso ainda esteja comentada.

Será necessário também a instalação Microsoft® ODBC Driver para SQL Server[Native Client] que irá depender de seu banco de dados no caso como exemplo passarei o link do Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 para SQL Server.

https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Após a instalação completa dos passos anteriores. você deverá restartar o apache.

se tudo estiver correto você poderá acessar novamente o phpinfo() e poderá pesquisar por sqlsrv [image: sqlsrv]

e em seguida por pdo_sqlsrv [image: pdo_sqlsrv]
<sub>(fonte: [synet.sk](http://www.synet.sk/images/cms/pdo_sqlsrv_phpinfo.png))</sub>
espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, mas o problema é tão antigo que nem tenho mais acesso ao mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia galera!!

Estava com o mesmo problema, realizei os passos indicados, porém, não tive sucesso na instalação da conexão Sql Server.

Versões:

- PHP = 5.6.21;
- SO  = Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1.

Instalei os seguintes componentes:

- Cópia das DLLs para a pasta ext do php: php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll e php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll (meu php está para Thread Safety conforme DLL "php5ts.dll");
- Adicionei no arquivo "php.ini" as extensões: "extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll" e "extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll";
- Na imagem abaixo, é possível notar que a extensão no foi habilitada.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar...

Obrigado!!

Comment: Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.

Comment: O site funciona diferente de um fórum, para entender as diferenças recomendo a leitura da [tour]