# Como conectar PHP com o SQLServer através do PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
try {

    $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=172.20.21.193,9090;Database=sgt","deb","123123");

    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("Erro na conexao com o banco de dados: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

mas está dando erro ao tentar conectar. O driver do PDO está instalado. Qual outra biblioteca ou driver devo instalar, para que minha aplicação acesse o banco de dados? A versão do PHP é a 5.6.9 (Linux Debian 8.1) e o SQLServer é 2008(o acesso será remoto).

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Este "could not find driver"

Comment: Vc precisa instalar ele primeiro, veja o procedimento nesse link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48078/91

Comment: Mesmo para Linux? Estes seriam os passos?

Comment: No Linux, não sei dizer, edite a pergunta e adicione essa informação com mais detalhes ajuda os outros usuários a responder melhor.

Comment: Tente o PDO_DBLIB: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-dblib.php ou o PDO_ODBC com driver para linux, conforme descrito aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Answer (score 4):

Consegui seguindo as orientações do link: https://alephnull.uk/content/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-php-ubuntu-using-pdo-odbc-and-freetds. A linha do código ficou assim: `$con = new PDO("dblib:host=172.20.21.193,9090;dbname=sgt", "deb", "123123");`

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema, porém a solução acima não me ajudou @Deb

Answer (score 0):

o Drive PDO sqlsrv não funciona no Linux com PHP 5.6, nesses casos use dblib.

Para PHP 7.0 ou superior pode usar o sqlsrv

Link Docker File Ubuntu 16.08 com PHP 7.0 e PDO sqlsrv 
https://github.com/bjverde/formDocker/blob/master/ubuntu_php7.0_mssql/ubuntu_apache_php70.Dockerfile