# Como conectar PHP 5.6 ao Sql Server 2008?

Tags: php, sql-server, conexão

Preciso de ligar a uma BD MS Sql Server 2008 com o PHP 5.6

Tenho 
Desenvolvimento:
Windows 7 64bits, com xampp

Produção Centos 7

Instalei os [drivers da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx).

Com esta linha de código

```
$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$db", "$user", "$pwd");
```

Dá erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86

Provavelmente não irá funcionar em Centos 7.

Qual a melhor solução?

Comment: Relacionado, talvez ajude: [Como conectar PHP com o SQLServer através do PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73279/91)

Answer (score 2):

Será necessário alguns arquivos .dll que você poderá encontrar no seguinte link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
Como seu PHP é o 5.6, Baixe o Arquivo SQLSRV32.

Após baixar o arquivo, você irá extrai-lo, lá você terá as dlls necessárias.

utilize o phpinfo(), para verificar qual o PHP Extension Build. [image: PHP Extension Build].
no caso do exemplo você terá que copiar as dlls que tenham _ts.dll do php 5.6, ou seja:
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll e php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll,
Copie estes arquivos para os respectivos diretórios,
`C:/.../php/ext` e também para o `C:/windows/system32/` e/ou para o `C:/windows/SysWOW64` caso sejá computador de 64bits.

Feito isso você deverá abrir o php.ini e na sessão de extension você deverá acrescentar as seguintes linhas:

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

[image: php.ini]
Será necessário também a instalação Microsoft® ODBC Driver para SQL Server[Native Client] que irá depender de seu banco de dados no caso como exemplo passarei o link do Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 para SQL Server.

https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Após a instalação completa dos passos anteriores. você deverá restartar o apache.

se tudo estiver correto você poderá acessar novamente o phpinfo() e poderá pesquisar por sqlsrv [image: sqlsrv]

e em seguida por pdo_sqlsrv [image: pdo_sqlsrv]
<sub>(fonte: [synet.sk](http://www.synet.sk/images/cms/pdo_sqlsrv_phpinfo.png))</sub>
espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, teria como você tentar a conexão utilizando o Driver ODBC? Não seise ajuda no seu caso, mas comigo deu certo assim:

`$conexao = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bancoDeDados; Uid=sa;Pwd=SenhaDoBanco;");`

Lembrando que vc deve habilitar o driver ODBC no PHP.ini...

Answer (score 0):

Eu consigo conectar no Sql Server 2008 com:

- Debian 8 e PHP 5.6 utilizo PDO com drive dblib
- Ubuntu 16.04 e PHP 7.0 utilizo PDO com drive sqlsrv, se desejar [aqui está link do DockerFile](https://github.com/bjverde/formDocker/blob/master/ubuntu_php7.0_mssql/ubuntu_apache_php70.Dockerfile) para montar essa maquina

```php
/***
 *  Get Data Source Name (DSN) do PDO
 *  Deixando o Semelhante getDsnPDO do formin, para evitar o problema da versão do Drive
 *  https://intratec.mpdft.mp.br/gitlab/Repositorio/Infraestrutura/Utils/formDin/blob/master/classes/webform/TPDOConnection.class.php#L481
 * @param string $host      - IP ou nome do servidor
 * @param string $database  - nome do banco
 * @return NULL|string
 */
function getDsnPDO($sgbd,$host,$database) {
    $dsn = null;

    if($sgbd=="mysql"){
        $port='3306';
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';port='.$port;
    } else {
        $port = '1433';
        if (PHP_OS == "Linux") {
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
                $driver = 'sqlsrv';
                $dsn = $driver.':Server='.$host.','.$port.';Database='.$database;
            } else {
                $driver = 'dblib';
                //$dsn = $driver.':version=7.2;charset=UTF-8;host=' . HOST . ';dbname=' . DATABASE . ';port=' . PORT;
                $dsn = $driver.':version=7.2;host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';port='.$port;
            }
        } else {
            $driver = 'sqlsrv';
            $dsn = $driver.':Server='.$host.','.$port.';Database='.$database;
        }
    }
    return $dsn;
}

function conecta() {        


    $hostname       = 'meuservidorbanco';
    $dbname         = 'banco';
    $username       = 'usuario';
    $password       = 'senha';


    try{
        $stringPDO = getDsnPDO($sgbd,$hostname,$dbname);
        $dbh = new PDO($stringPDO,$username,$password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    return $dbh;
}
```