# Erro ao tentar conectar bd MSSQL Server usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Não consigo acessar o banco de dados MS SQL SERVER usando PDO. Já fiz de tudo, a melhor resposta que consegui foi com o código abaixo, mas continuo recebendo umas resposta de erro:

> Erro de Conexão SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)

Meu servidor é **CentOS 5.11** (64 bits)

Alguma ideia?

```
<?php
  try {
    $hostname = "db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br,1500";
    $dbname = "LexManager_GadelCampinas";
    $username = "gadelview";
    $pw = "password";
    $pdo = new PDO ('dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname', '$username', '$pw');
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Erro de Conexão " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
?>
```

---

Alterei o código e parece funcionar a conexão com **sqlserver** . Agora é descobrir como consultar a tabela e mostrar os dados :). Alguma dica?

O código está correto?

```
<?php
  try {
    $hostname = "db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br";
    $port = 1500;
    $dbname = "LexManager_GadelCampinas";
    $username = "gadelview";
    $pw = "password";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
    echo "Conexão ok";
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual erro está dando? Não use o `mysql_*` ele está depreciado, acho que sua melhor opção é contratar um freelance.

Comment: PS: 1500 provavelmente deve ser a porta do MySQL que foi alterada e não parte do endereço pro servidor.

Comment: @lvcs obrigado pela ajuda na minha pergunta. Queremos contratar um freela para criar um app, mas precisamos ter um modelo para apresentar para o patrocinador, por isso estou quebrando a cabeça para criar esse MVB. Se puder me dar umas dicas, vou pesquisando e testanto por aqui.

Comment: Mais ou menos um ano atrás fiz um projeto pra ajudar iniciantes com operações com banco de dados, usando `PDO` (driver mais recente para banco de dados). Você pode acessar nesse link: https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/MinPDO nele há um breve tutorial e como usar, espero que ajude. Para fazer a conexão é bem simples, assim como consultar e alterar registros, no arquivo index.php do repositório tem uma descrição de como tudo funciona.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, obrigado! Mas voltando aos 1500, como devo utilizar essa informação, ou seja, como declaro essa porta no código?

Comment: Se realmente for a porta basta alterar para `db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500` caso continue com erro tente só com `db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br`. E caso ainda dê erro, poste qual erro esta dando.

Comment: db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500
Erro: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500' (1)

db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br
Erro: Estou esperando há alguns segundos sem resposta do servidor.

Comment: Sem a porta, o erro é outro:

Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:

XID: 33940816

Varnish cache server

Comment: Estranho, esse erro sem a porta, parece que encontrou o host do banco de dados, mas deu algum erro interno lá.

Comment: Já fiz uma pergunta pro pessoal que gerou o acesso, vamos ver. Obrigado.

Comment: Recebi um retorno deles, o problema é que eles usam SQL Server :|

"A interface que você está utilizando aponta uma string de conexão MySQL... O nosso banco de dados é SQL Server, provavelmente você vai conseguir usar com o driver mssql_connect, ou sqlsrv_connect..."

Comment: Você pode usar `$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$host};Database={$db}", $user , $pass);`  Agora sim, no `$host` deve ter o ',1500'

Comment: Ou assim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73279/como-conectar-php-com-o-sqlserver-através-do-pdo

Comment: @lvcs Pelo menos deu erro de conexão :) a mensagem que aparece agora é "Erro de Conexão could not find driver" 

Dei uma pesquisada e parece que meu servidor (locaweb) não é compatível. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Mudei para dblib '$pdo = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", '$username', '$pw');' agora o erro é **Erro de Conexão SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)**

Comment: O primeiro erro é o que driver do banco de dados não está instalado na máquina, o segundo você pode tentar consertar colocando `db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500` (dois pontos).. Se essa tentativa não der, então não sei mais como proceder.

Comment: @lvcs Estou usando seu projeto no GitHub, fiz as configurações de acordo com as orientações, fiz um teste de conexão do BD, deu tudo certo, mas agora, quando eu tento rodar a consulta(), por exemplo, recebo um erro **Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)** Você tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? [http://pethood.com.br/pontestore/MinPDO-master/ex/consultar.php]

Answer (score 1):

Quando roda o script em windows creio eu que usa-se a virgula assim (`dblib:host=HOST,PORTA`):

```
new PDO('dblib:host=db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br,1500;dbname=<banco>', '<usuario>', '<senha>');
```

Se for linux (ou like-unix) creio que o correto seja usar `:`, assim:

```
new PDO('dblib:host=db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500;dbname=<banco>', '<usuario>', '<senha>');
```

Fora que você usou `'` apóstrofos e tentou passar variáveis assim `'$variavel'`, o php não reconhece isso como variável, ele vai pensar que é apenas uma `string`, vou pode então concatenar ou usar aspas normais `"`

Faça isso:

```
$hostname = "db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500";
$dbname = "LexManager_GadelCampinas";
$username = "gadelview";
$pw = "password";
$pdo = new PDO ('dblib:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname='. $dbname, $username, $pw);
```

Ou com aspas (os demais parametros não precisam de aspas)

```
$hostname = "db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500";
$dbname = "LexManager_GadelCampinas";
$username = "gadelview";
$pw = "password";
$pdo = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pw);
```

Se o problema for realmente com a virgula, pode fazer isto:

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    $hostname = "db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br,1500";
} else {
    $hostname = "db-gadel-campinas.lexos.com.br:1500";
}
```

Comment: Alterei o código, fiz todos os testes, mas ainda não deu certo. Ou não aparece nenhuma mensagem, ou dá erro de conexão. Obrigado pela ajuda. Talvez só dê certo criando uma api. Estou tentando. Obrigado.

Comment: @ÁllanFidelisToledo mas notou que você tinha usado o nome do host errado, é provavel que seja um erro de digitação seu.

Comment: Conversei com meu fornecedor do SAP, ele que criou o view do banco de dados, e ele me disse que dificilmente vou conseguir fazer essa conexão por PHP, ele sugeriu criar um api em C# que acesse o bd e exporte para mysql, assim terei mais facilidade para desenvolver a aplicação. Você tem alguma ideia / indicação de como fazer esse api? Já pesquisei muito e não consegui resolver.

Comment: Eu recomendaria mesmo o uso do [PHP SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) como driver do PHP para o MS SQL Server. Mas respondendo sua pergunta: com o Visual Studio 2015 você consegue (na verdade, versões anteriores também). Use ASP.NET Visual C#, se quiser seguir a indicação do seu fornecedor. No site da Microsoft você pode encontrar [tutoriais passo-a-passo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) de como construir APIs mais simples com fins de demonstração (nada de produção aqui).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) é uma distribuição Red Hat Linux

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway Sim, eu sei, conheço.