# microsoft sql server conexão e configuração em php

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tentando conectar com um database microsoft sql server utilizando php.
A versão do php é:

**PHP Version 5.6.3**

e o erro que dá é

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\aloha.php on line 7**

Tentei usar o comando:

```
<?php  
$myServer = "server";
$myUser = "user";
$myPass = "senha";
$myDB = "mydb";

$conn = mssql_connect($myServer,$myUser,$myPass);
if (!$conn)
{ 
die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} 
$db_selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} 
?>
```

Porém dá erro, pois parece que meu PHP não está configurado para conectar.

Eu fui no php.ini e descomentei o

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

porém mesmo assim não funcionou.

Os dados do phpinfo achei muito grande para postar aqui, então se precisar de algum dado específico pergunte aqui.

Comment: Vc está usando microsoft's extension:?

Comment: Não pode usar outra API, como o PDO ou sqlsrv? é conexão com SQL Server 7 ou 2000?

Comment: Não estou usando o microsoft's extension e sim posso usar outra API, se puder me dar uma solução. Só desejo fazer a conexão (Não importa qual função utilizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php) informa que essa extensão não está mais disponível desde o php5.3. A recomendação é utilizar outras APIs como [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php).

> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

Exemplo com sqlsrv:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'ip ou servidor\instancia';
$db = 'test';
$usuario = 'user';
$senha = 'pass';        

$conexao = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, array('Database' => $db, 'UID' => $usuario, 'PWD' => $senha));
```

Relacionado:

[Drivers PDO para SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48078/91)

[Documentação SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php)

Comment: Eu tentei usar o sqlsrv e deu o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\aloha.php on line 5

Comment: @FelipeJorge é necessario instalar a extensão antes, veja o link drivers PDO para SQL Server, lá descreve como instalar as duas extensões.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.setup.php

No manual não teve gente que contribuiu na configuração,

Comment: @FelipeJorge o link do seu comentário é a lista de funçãos, esse outro mostra a instalação http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48078/91

Comment: O que seria o \instancia?

Comment: @FelipeJorge, as vezes o ip não funciona, então vc coloca `nomeDaMaquina\noDoSQLServer`