# Conexão com sql server PHP

Tags: php

Estou usando uma conexão para mysql server, só que preciso conexão com sql server 2008. Segue código abaixo que estou usando:

```
    <?php

    $_SG['conectaServidor'] = true;    
    $_SG['abreSessao'] = true;         
    $_SG['caseSensitive'] = true;     
    $_SG['validaSempre'] = true;       

    $_SG['servidor'] = 'localhost';    
    $_SG['usuario'] = 'root';          
    $_SG['senha'] = '';                
    $_SG['banco'] = 'db';            
    $_SG['paginaLogin'] = 'login.php'; 
    $_SG['tabela'] = 'usuarios';       



    if ($_SG['conectaServidor'] == true) {
      $_SG['link'] = mssql_connect($_SG['servidor'], $_SG['usuario'], $_SG['senha']) or die("MySQL: Não foi possível conectar-se ao servidor [".$_SG['servidor']."].");
      mssql_select_db($_SG['banco'], $_SG['link']) or die("MySQL: Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados [".$_SG['banco']."].");
    }

    if ($_SG['abreSessao'] == true)
      session_start();


    function validaUsuario($usuario, $senha) {
      global $_SG;
      $cS = ($_SG['caseSensitive']) ? 'BINARY' : '';

      $nusuario = addslashes($usuario);
      $nsenha = addslashes($senha);

      $sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome` FROM `".$_SG['tabela']."` WHERE ".$cS." `usuario` = '".$nusuario."' AND ".$cS." `senha` = '".$nsenha."' LIMIT 1";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

      if (empty($resultado)) {

        return false;
      } else {

        $_SESSION['usuarioID'] = $resultado['id']; 
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome']; 

        if ($_SG['validaSempre'] == true) {

          $_SESSION['usuarioLogin'] = $usuario;
          $_SESSION['usuarioSenha'] = $senha;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }

    function protegePagina() {
      global $_SG;
      if (!isset($_SESSION['usuarioID']) OR !isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome'])) {

        expulsaVisitante();
      } else {

        if ($_SG['validaSempre'] == true) {
            if (!validaUsuario($_SESSION['usuarioLogin'], $_SESSION['usuarioSenha'])) {
            expulsaVisitante();
            }
        }
      }
    }

    function expulsaVisitante() {
      global $_SG;
        unset($_SESSION['usuarioID'], $_SESSION['usuarioNome'], $_SESSION['usuarioLogin'], $_SESSION['usuarioSenha']);
        header("Location: ".$_SG['paginaLogin']);
    }
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: A duvida é que preciso fazer conexão com mssql não mysql só não sei como

Comment: Já tentou ou pesquisou conexoes em PDO? Veja se [**esse artigo**](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/16221/php/desenvolvendo-com-pdo-php-data-objects/) ajuda a elucidar sobre o tema:

Comment: Essas funções já foram aposentadas, você deve usar o PDO ou sqlsrv. [microsoft sql server conexão e configuração em php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101524/91)