# Conexão banco de dados sql server 2008 PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
try {

$con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=ip;Database=nome","nome","12345");

$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  


} catch (PDOException $e) {
die ("Erro na conexao com o banco de dados: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

Estou tentando conectar num banco sql server 2008, e estou usando o xampp pois a tela fica branca. Ja verifiquei as extension no php.ini e tudo mais.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao site. Você consegue visualizar o console do navegador para tentar verificar o erro?

Comment: Obrigado.Sim verifiquei, pois não mostra nada também

Comment: Você precisa verificar se ocorre erro. Habilite seu php para mostrar os erros

Comment: [Olhe essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48078/drivers-pdo-para-sql-server), pode te ajudar muito.

Comment: Já fiz todo esse procedimento, e meu php já está com o (display_errors = On), a pagina fica simplesmente em branco não sei se é erro de código ou de php.

Comment: Qual versão php está usando? tela em branco é erro de programação, adicione essas  duas linha no inicio da página, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Não esqueça de ver no, `phpinfo()` se a extensão foi instalada/carregada corretamente.

Comment: Aparentemente está tudo certo a versão do php que uso é a 5.6.14 e contem as extension **php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll**  e **php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll**, o driver sqlsrv pdo também consta como instalado. Mesmo com essa linha de código continua em branco a página.

Comment: Então está tudo certo, só faltou fazer um consulta, como não tem nenhuma saida a página vai em branco mesmo.

Comment: Certo, deu certo com consulta haha obrigado.

Comment: No dsn, troca o ip, pelo nome da máquina\instancia, algo como `Server=servidorDeBanco\NomeDoSQLServer`;

Comment: É que o server não ta hospedado na máquina.

Comment: Ótimo, que bom você conseguiu! Agora precisamos criar uma resposta correta para sua pergunta, para que outros usuários também possam ser ajudados assim como você. Qual comentário foi fundamental para resolver sua situação? Se todos ajudaram, então crie uma resposta para sua pergunta.

Comment: O código acima está certo, porém não ira mostrar nada na tela se não fizer alguma consulta. Abaixo eu usei este código para testar a conexão e ver se retornava algo: `$consulta = $con->query("SELECT Dslogin, DsSenha FROM SISWEBUSU;");
 while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Login: {$linha['Dslogin']} - Senha: {$linha['DsSenha']}<br />";
}`

Comment: A resposta do rray clareou tudo.