# SQL injection com PHP + SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server

Como posso prevenir SQL injection vindo de um input via POST utilizando PHP + SQLServer. (Utizando Microsoft SQL Server => mmsql)

Estou fazendo a abstração de dados de um BD que roda MYSQLI e neste caso é feita desta maneira.

```
$Email= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['Email']);
$Senha= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['Senha']);
```

Comment: O PDO é uma alternativa. Qual driver está usando?

Comment: A aplicação utiliza mssql JDBC no SQL

Comment: mssql a antiga? sobre o pdo => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91

Comment: ODBC ou JDBC? tem coisa estranha aí.

Comment: atual http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mssql.php @rray

Comment: no BD SQL está /Volumes/RazorSQL/RazorSQL.app/Contents/Java/drivers/jtds/jtds12.jar e net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver foi quase rs..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34378/discussion-between-denis-and-rray).

Comment: A extensão mssql foi removida do php7 e desde a 5.3 para windows ela não é inlcuida é altamente recomendado não utilizar ela.

Answer (score 2):

Existe dois drivers para fazer conexão com o SQL Server o PDO e o SQLSRV, Tem várias questões sobre o PDO especificas para o SQL Server, desde a a [instação e configuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48078/91), criação da conexão e os [demais aspectos da biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91).

Criação da conexão:

```
$servidor = 'ip ou servidor\instancia';
$db = 'test';
$usuario = 'user';
$senha = 'pass';        

$conexao = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, array('Database' => $db, 'UID' => $usuario, 'PWD' => $senha));
```

Escapar caracteres não previne nem resolve o problema de sql injections como mostra [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50841/91), a melhor forma de atacar esse problema é filtrar as entradas do usuário adequadamente e utilizar prepared statements.

Para DML(insert, update ou delete) faça esse código, isto é apenas um exemplo por favor não armazena senhas em formato de texto puro no banco.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(email, nome, senha) VALUES(?,?,?)";

$email = "doge@wow.com";
$nome = "Doge";
$senha = "wowsuchsecret";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conexao, $sql, array($email, $nome, $senha));
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

Para selects:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conexao, $sql);
if( $stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['nome']." - ".$row['email']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente isso não funciona pra mim pois me conecto remotamente via mssql_connect