# Criar uma query no PHP para inserir na tabela

Tags: php, sql-server

Olá, como posso criar uma query em php que clicar no botão inserir na tabela os códigos?

Meu código:

```
    <?php

$error = null;
$sucses = null;

if(isset($_POST['Promo'])) {
        $AwardID = $_POST['AwardID'];
        $ActiveID = $_POST['ActiveID'];
        $PullDown = $_POST['PullDown'];
        if($AwardID == null)
            $error.= 'Houve um erro em AwardID!<br />';
        if($error == null) {
            $q = q("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Active_Number] ([AwardID], [ActiveID], [PullDown]) VALUES('$AwardID', '50', 'False')");
            $sucses = 'O código: "'.$AwardID.'" foi validado com sucesso.<br />';
        }
        }



function geraSenha($tamanho = 18, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = false, $simbolos = false)
{
$lmin = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$lmai = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$num = '1234567890';
$simb = '!@#$%*-';
$retorno = '';
$caracteres = '';
$caracteres .= $lmin;
if ($maiusculas) $caracteres .= $lmai;
if ($numeros) $caracteres .= $num;
if ($simbolos) $caracteres .= $simb;
$len = strlen($caracteres);
for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
$rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
$retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
}
return $retorno;
}
?>
<div id="tbtoolbar">
<center>
<input name='AwardID' id='AwardID' type='text' maxlength='40' value='<?php echo geraSenha(18, true, false, false); ?>' readonly />
    <button name='Promo' id="Promo" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validar código</button>
    <?php echo '<center><div><font color="red">'.$error. '</font></div></center>'; echo '<center><div><font color="green">'.$sucses. '</font></div></center>'; ?></center>
    </center>
</div>
<script>
```

Comment: Quero saber como faz a query, lá só explica a conexão

Comment: "não entendi muito bem a parte de conexão", entendi errado então.

Comment: Como faz a conexão do PHP com SQL, quero saber como que executa a query do PHP pro SQL

Comment: qual banco de dados vc está usando?
MySQL? Postgres? Primeiro vc tem que criar uma conexão com o banco. Depois usa as funções relativas ao seu bando de dados ou PDO, passando sua variável de conexão como parâmetro. À propósito, o banco de dados e suas tabelas já devem ter sido criadas antes.

Comment: SQL Server 2014, poderia me explicar em código?

Comment: [Aqui tem um exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108610/91) usando a lib sqlsrv.

Comment: Tentei fazer mas não consegui como posto o código que tentei fazer?

Comment: Infelizmente parece que ligar PHP com SQL Server não é tão trivial quanto fazê-lo com MySQL ou Postgres.
Recomendo você a ler a documentação desde a Instalação do SQL Server Express Edition em seu ambiente de desenvolvimento. Pode ser necessário instalar dlls para rodar com o PHP.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mssql.php