# Não consigo conectar o PHP no SQL Server 2014

Tags: php, sql

Boa tarde galera!

Criei uma pequena aplicação para testar minha conexão do PHP com SQL Server 2014, mas não estou conseguindo conectar. Já vi inúmeros fóruns na web e inclusive aqui algumas dúvidas parecidas com a minha, mas ainda não achei a solução.

Meu código que estou tentando conectar ao banco é o:

```
<?php
   $connect = odbc_connect("araguaina","sa","@@2013DOT**flex");
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM cd_empresa";
   $result = odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
?>
```

Não sei se a informação é válida, mas estou usando Wamp e me parece que não tenho drive para rodar o sqlsrvr, conforme mostra o print do phpinfo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Chegou a faze esse [Drivers PDO para SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48079/91) procedimento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez você devesse tentar a PDO com o plugin SQLsrv (isto é o que estou usando para conectar ao software do meu outro chefe que usa o banco de dados do SQL Server 2014):

```
$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $server . ";Database=" . $database, $username, $password);
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Você pode baixar o plugin aqui

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36434

No Xampp, você deve copiar a dll na pasta:

```
C:\xampp\php\ext
```

E você deve adicionar essa linha ao seu php.ini

```
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

**Nota**: 
Não se esqueça de reiniciar seu servidor para que ele possa levar em conta o novo arquivo php.ini.

---

> **OBS. PHP 7**

As DLLs de extensões do PHP são compiladas para funcionar em uma única versão do PHP. A DLL do PHP 5.6 irá travar no PHP 7, e a do PHP 7 também vai travar no PHP 7.1. Então, num primeiro momento, garanta que esteja utilizando **somente** a versão correta na pasta de `ext` e no `php.ini`

Se atente também que o PHP é compilado de [duas formas no Windows](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.1): **thread safe** e **non thread safe**. Isso também influencia em qual extensão você deve usar (novamente, não misture alhos com bugalhos).

Ah, quase esquecendo, a partir do PHP 7 também temos uma compilação para x64 e outra para x86. De novo, é preciso escolher a versão correta aqui também.

Supondo que você está usando a versão **Thread Safe** (a que vem junto com o XAMPP/Apache geralmente), baixe a extensão mais recente para trabalhar com o SQL Server. A forma mais fácil é [olhar no repositório do github do driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/), na parte de releases e baixar somente a versão que você deseja.

Hoje o suporte para PHP 7.1 ainda está em preview, e a versão mais recente [é essa](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/4.1.4-Windows).

Baixe somente o zip para o PHP 7.1, escolha a arquitetura, thread safe ou não e extraia somente eles na pasta `ext` e insira no `php.ini`.

```
// suporte PDO
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
// sem PDO
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
```

Por fim, se algo não der certo, pode ser preciso atualizar também o [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420). O SQL Server Express 2014 usa a versão 11 deve driver para conexão, e pelo que me lembre não sei se a nova versão do driver para PHP precisa que você atualize o ODBC também.

Comment: Eu já fiz todos os procedimentos que vc descreveu acima, só não achei o arquivo php.ini na pasta de instalação do PHP dentro do Xampp. Os arquivos que achei foram: php.ini-development, php.ini-production e adicionei a extensão de suporte ao PDO nelas (meu php está como Thread Safe habilitado). Mesmo assim continuo não conseguindo acessar o sql server :(

Comment: o php.ini na pasta do php: **https://imgur.com/a/uvfJd**  e pelo painel do xampp: **https://imgur.com/a/XwSgY**

Comment: Já adicionei nesse arquivo também.

Veja se coloquei certo com o ponto e virgula na frente:

;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll

Comment: .retira o **;**

Comment: Agora apareceu outro erro:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver

Comment: Eu adicionei as seguintes dlls:

[https://imgur.com/a/h9MWT

Comment: A versão do meu php é a 7.1.8

Comment: Esse erro ocoreu poque ele não encontrou o drive do SQL Server. EM **extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll** coloca **extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll**

Comment: coloco no arquivo php.ini também?

Comment: não está faltando um "L" no final?
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dl

Comment: @DiegoGrossi Sim. Corrigido. esse código e no php.ini

Comment: Ele está retornando o mesmo erro. Já não sei mais o que faço :(
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\rodoviaria-araguaina-testando-sql\teste.php:7

Comment: Veja por favor se meu código está certo?

`<?php
$server = "192.168.1.11";
$database = "ARAGUAINA";
$username = "sa";
$password = "@@2013DOT**flex";

$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $server . ";Database=" . $database, $username, $password);
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
`

Comment: Sim está. no php.ini altere **php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll** pelo nome dos outros drives que vc instalou para ver

Comment: Amigo, acredito que consegui conectar ao banco, pois não retornou nenhum erro. Preciso apenas saber como faço consulta no banco usando a conexão PDO.
Seria: 
`function exibeUltimoElemento($conexao){

 $query = "select Cd_Empresa from cd_empresa";
 $resultado = pdo_exec($conexao, $query);
 $empresas = 0;

 while ($empresa_array = pdo_fetch_row($resultado)) {
  $empresas ++;
 }

 return $empresas;
}`

Comment: Um exemplo em imagem: **http://imgur.com/a/WZ0kK** . Um tutorial de PDO: **http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-php-pdo/24973**  Obs: os comandos PDO são iguais para todos os bancos de dados. o que pode mudar e so sua query SQL

Comment: Meu amigo, muito obrigado! Você salvou meu dia! Problema resolvido, já consigo acessar e consultar meu banco!

Obrigado mais uma vez! ;)

Comment: Sou novo no Fórum. Onde coloco o tópico como resolvido?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/DWe55

Comment: Resolvido! Valeu!

Answer (score -2):

Olha eu não sei se irá ajudar muito, mas acredito que há diferentes modos de fazer uma conexão, eu também uso o Wamp. Então acho que apenas pode mudar a forma como conecta. por exemplo:

```
<?php

function getConnection(){
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $senha = "123456";
    $banco = "programacao";
    $link = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
    $db = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
        if(!$link)
            {
                echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
            }
}
?>
```

Certifique-se de linkar este arquivo com oque você fez, no caso a pagina principal. Pode usar um include se preferir...

Boa Sorte !! >o<

Comment: Ele precisa conectar ao `SQL Server 2014` não no `mysql`

Comment: Alis, meu código com a sua sugestão ficou assim:

` //conexao com o sql 
$host = "192.168.1.11"; $user = "as"; $pass = "@@2013DOT**flex"; $banco = "ARAGUAINA"; $conexao = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mssql_get_last_message()); mssql_select_db($banco,$conexao) or die (mssql_get_last_message());`

Comment: Mas ele me traz o mesmo erro quando tento conectar via odbc_connect. Segue o erro:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()