# Como configurar o XAMPP para Sql Server 2014

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

Alguém consegue me ensinar como configurar o XAMPP para Sql Server 2014? Estou em um projeto que não permite Mysql (PHPMYADMIN).

Comment: [Drivers PDO para SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48078/91)

Answer (score 1):

Flavio, você pode baixar os `drivers do SQL Server` (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) ou usar o PDO.

Coloque os arquivos em `c:\xampp\php\ext`

No `php.ini` defina as extensões, como exemplo:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dl 
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

OBS: Se não me engano, no PHP 7 não estão funcionando os drivers.
Tenho funcionando no 5.6 normalmente.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao XAMPP para Windows 7.0.21 vou trocar para versão 5.6 então..  Obrigado Raoni BZ!

Comment: Flávio, faça no 5.6 (Version 3.2 supports PHP 5.6, 5.5, and 5.4 on Windows) pois esse é certeza que está funcionando e assim você se familiariza com o processo, aí depois pode tentar no 7.0 (Version 4.0 supports PHP 7.0+ on Windows and Linux). Não esqueça de nos dar um retorno, assim ajuda o próximo !

Answer (score 1):

Cuidado para não baixar os driver errados, eu passei um sufoco fazendo tudo certinho, de vários tutoriais e nada funcionava, até formatei o pc.

Depois de longos 4 dias tentando, finalmente descobri o erro, eu estava usando os drivers na versão do Windows, que no meu caso é 64x, porém o Xamp era 86x, eu deveria ter usado os drivers 86x na pasta ...\php\ext\