# Driver SQL Server no WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, wampserver

Estou tentando instalar o driver do SQL Server para o php 5.5.12 (x64) mas ainda não consegui

Baixei as dll's do [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) oficial, e acrescentei no php.ini

Apareceram na lista de extensões do PHP mas não aparecerem no php info, e ao tentar fazer alguma conexão ele dizia driver não encontrado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48079/54152) apareceu no php info porém ao tentar uma consulta a mensagem muda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mensagem de erro é assim:

> **SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
>   or the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Native Client to communicate with SQL
>   Server. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server
>   2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x64:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712**

Estou usando o wampserver x64
Apache 2.4.9
PHP 5.5.12

Existe alguma forma de configurar sem precisar para mudar 32 bits ?

Comment: A mensagem de erro informa que deve instalar também o driver ODBC, de 64 bits. // Qual a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: 64 bits é a versão