# Erro Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

**Estou tentando fazer uma conexão do sql server com o php7, inseri os dados do banco na classe do php, inseri as extensões na pasta do php no xamp, e no php.ini, porém é exibido esse erro quando executo o código.**

***Meu Código***

```
$conn = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Database=dbphpsql;server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; ConnectionPooling=0", "sa", "root");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios ORDER BY deslogin");

$stmt ->execute();

$results = $stmt ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($results as $row) {

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

        echo "<strong>" . $key . ":</strong>" . $value . "<br/>";

    }

    echo "====================================================<br>";

}

var_dump($results) . "<br>";
```

Comment: [Habilitou o driver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48079/91) do sql server (PDO)?

Comment: Sim. Já habilitei.

Comment: Confesso que não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Olhou se dll está na pasta e está registrada no php.ini? acho que não aparece nada no `phpinfo()` ou `php -m`?

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo este código por um curso online, adicionei as dll's que disponibilizaram para ver qual é a do meu pc.

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll

Comment: seu php é o 7 ou 7.1?

Comment: PHP version: 7.2.3

Comment: Tem como trocar o 7.2 por 7.1 ou 7? em teoria o driver do 7.1 deveria ser compatível com o 7.2